# How to resolve type annotations to function local types with PEP563 enabled

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

In Python 4.0, type annotations like

```
foo:int
```

will be treated as a string and need to be dynamically resolved.  This can be selected with python 3.7 using `from __future import annotations`.
The `typing.get_type_hints`  function will try and turn string annotations and other forward references into actual types.

I need slightly different semantics than `typing.get_type_hints` because I'd like to handle class inheritance differently, although it looks from examination of the code like `get_type_hints` doesn't handle this case anyway.
Imagine the following code:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

def foo():
    class bar: pass
    def baz(a: bar): pass
    return baz
```

if I look at the annotations of the returned function I'll see something like

```py
{'a': 'bar'}
```

Roughly what `typing.get_type_hints` does in this case is tries to find a locals and globals dictionary to pass into eval.
But how do I do that  here?  How do I find a set of locals where `a` will resolve to the `bar` class local to the call to `foo` that produced the baz I am examining?

Comment: *Which* ``bar`` class local to ``foo``? Every time you call ``foo``, a new ``bar`` class is created. What is your expected result?

Comment: I clarified that I'm looking to find the bar class local to the call to `foo` producing the `baz` I have, just like I get without from __future__ import annotations

Comment: I don't see how that is possible (or even well-defined). In the example, the ``bar`` class is unreachable the moment ``foo`` terminates. At what point do you want to resolve ``bar``? During ``foo`` or after it?

Comment: If I knew how it was possible I wouldn't ask the question.  It's certainly well defined.